# how to detect overflow

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to detect the overflow.

I am trying to list user images in a single row and if it's overflowed depending on the device screen size/changes in screen orientation.

I tried to do this using media queries but no luck.I am using Ionic 3

.html:

```
<ion-row style="padding: 7px;" nowrap>
  <ion-row style="overflow: hidden; height: 55px;">
       <ion-col col-auto *ngFor="let image of images">
            <img src="assets/images/image.png" />
        </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-col *ngIf="showButton" col-auto align-self-center>
     <img src="assets/images/more3.svg">
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

.ts:

```
showButton = true;

/////
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            public modalCtrl: ModalController,
            private postService: PostService,
            private app: App,
            private el: ElementRef){

  this.images = new Array(10);
}
```

[image]

I am trying to hide the button `more` when the row is no longer overflowed and items fit the screen and show when it's not.

any suggestions, thanx

Answer (score 0):

ok , I found a work around , but it's not the best solution

.html:

```
///
<ion-row id="innerRow" style="overflow: hidden; height: 55px;">   //added id
   <ion-col col-auto *ngFor="let image of images">
        <img src="assets/images/image.png" />
    </ion-col>
</ion-row> 
////
```

.ts:

```
showButton = true;

 /////
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
        public modalCtrl: ModalController,
        private postService: PostService,
        private app: App,
        private ngZone: NgZone){

   this.images = new Array(10);

   window.onresize = (e) => {                      // detect window resize
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
       let row = document.getElementById('innerRow');
          this.showButton = false;                 // reset
             if (this.isOverFlowed(row)){
                this.showButton = true;
             }
         });
     };
   }
} 

 ngAfterViewInit(){
  let row = document.getElementById('innerRow');
    if (this.isOverFlowed(row)){
        this.showButton = true;
    }
  }

  isOverFlowed(element){
    return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight ||element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth;
  }
```

I am open to any suggestion upon improving this code, thanx